# Disable or Override Ribbon/CommandBar commands in MSWord using VBA

Tags: vba, ms-office, ms-word

First of all I'm going to state right out that I've never worked with VB in the context of coding macros before - my skills lie in other areas (PHP, Javascript, getting there with C#, etc). However, I've been asked by a colleague to lock down a document so that the user cannot change font faces, sizes or colours but does still have access to bold, italic, underline etc.

I started out by protecting the document and restricting formatting but this is far too restrictive - effectively only allowing the user to apply premade styles - which is going to be unintuitive for the users who are not used to working with styles.

So I've resorted to trying to writing a macro to do the job, but unfortunately I'm at the really pointy end of the learning curve and I honestly don't know where to start.

You're going to laugh at me but so far this is all I have in my `ThisDocument`.

```
Private Sub Document_Open()

End Sub
```

Ermmmm... help!

Cheers

Iain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iain, this is a pretty common need. Here's a good information page on what will get you started: [Using VBA to Control Built-In Commands in the 2007 Office System](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd627337.aspx)

Comment: Hi Otaku. Sorry for the late response, I asked the question a while ago and ended up coming at the problem from another angle. However, your response is very useful and I will keep it saved for whenever I have to do this sort of thing again. VBA is really not my strong suit, haha :). Thanks very much for taking the time to respond to my question, very much appreciated.

- Iain

Answer (score 0):

I think you could write a macro that removed tools from the toolbar, menus, maybe even keyboard shortcuts. Not sure how you'd reverse it though when they opened another document.

Maybe a better solution is to use an application to edit only certain text fields that you define and which ultimately change text in a word document?